# How to debug JMeter the error JsonToken EndArray is not valid

Tags: jmeter

Before hand will be some images as I don't know how to explain them better.

I have an HTTP Request POST that has the parameters below:

{"ShiftId":${Param_S02_ShiftId},"Date":null,"StartTime":"${Param_S02_Pick_Date}T00:00:00.000Z","EndTime":"${Param_S02_Pick_Date}T23:00:00.000Z","RouteTemplateId":${Param_S02_RouteTemplateId},"VehicleId":${Param_S02_VehicleId},"SelectedEmployees":[{"RouteTemplateRoleId":${Param_S02_RoleId_1_driver},"EmployeeId":${Param_S02_1_driver}},{"RouteTemplateRoleId":${Param_S02_RoleId_2_driver},"EmployeeId":${Param_S02_2_driver}],"TeamBoardId":${Param_S02_Teamboard}}

[image]

As you can see this is the same API sent by the browser

[image]

The problem is that I am getting this error message that I could not find the solution aroud.

{"message": "JsonToken EndArray is not valid for closing JsonType Object. Path 'SelectedEmployees[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qhtcn.png)', line 1, position 237.","type":"Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException","stackTrace":"   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader.ValidateEnd(JsonToken endToken)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParsePostValue(Boolean ignoreComments)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.Read()\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JContainer.ReadContentFrom(JsonReader r, JsonLoadSettings settings)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JContainer.ReadTokenFrom(JsonReader reader, JsonLoadSettings options)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Load(JsonReader reader, JsonLoadSettings settings)\r\n   at ApiService.EntityObjectServiceController`2.ParseSaveRequestAsync() in C:\\a\\1\\s\\API\\src\\Framework\\ApiService\\EntityObjectServiceController.NETStandard.cs:line 151\r\n   at ApiService.EntityObjectServiceController`2.Create() in C:\a\1\s\API\src\Framework\ApiService\EntityObjectServiceController.NETStandard.cs:line 123\r\n   at lambda_method3708(Closure , Object )\r\n   at g__Awaited|26_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)"}

[image]

Do I need to add something in the Header?

[image]

Maybe is something with this part of the call where I have 0 and 1

[image]

Comment: The C# controller cannot parse the JSON payload, can you show the payload jMeter sends with the request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're sending an invalid JSON, your `SelectedEmployees` [array](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_arrays.asp) is missing closing bracked `]`, my expectation is that you need to amend your payload to something like:

```
{
  "ShiftId": ${Param_S02_ShiftId},
  "Date": null,
  "StartTime": "${Param_S02_Pick_Date}T00:00:00.000Z",
  "EndTime": "${Param_S02_Pick_Date}T23:00:00.000Z",
  "RouteTemplateId": ${Param_S02_RouteTemplateId},
  "VehicleId": ${Param_S02_VehicleId},
  "SelectedEmployees": [
    {
      "RouteTemplateRoleId": ${Param_S02_RoleId_1_driver},
      "EmployeeId": ${Param_S02_1_driver}
    },
    {
      "RouteTemplateRoleId": ${Param_S02_RoleId_2_driver},
      "EmployeeId": ${Param_S02_2_driver}
    }
  ],
  "TeamBoardId": ${Param_S02_Teamboard}
}
```

once you start sending syntactically correct JSON at least this error will go away, you can test it against i.e. [online JSON validator](https://jsonlint.com/)

Going forward given you're capable of successfully execute the request using your browser you can just record it using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) or [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732579-The-BlazeMeter-Chrome-Extension-Record-JMeter-Selenium-or-Synchronized-JMeter-and-Selenium)

Comment: Great, the problem was the bracked ], thank you for all you help Dmitri